# grails null value in dynamic select list

Tags: list, select, grails

I have followed the tutorial on http://grails.org/AJAX-Driven+SELECTs+in+GSP and successfully created a drop down list that is populated based on the selection of a previous list.  The problem I am running into is that I need to allow the auto populated list to have a null value as this field is not required.  I am sure this is simple enough but I just can't seem to find any way to do this.

My code is the same as posted on the website above so I will avoid duplicating it here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right before the `// Rebuild the select` add in a blank option. For example:

```
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.text = ""
opt.value = ""
try {
  rselect.add(opt, null) // standards compliant; doesn't work in IE
} catch(ex) {
  rselect.add(opt) // IE only
}
// Rebuild the select
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing all the code yourself, you could either use this [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/dnasir/jquery-cascading-dropdown) or this [Grails plugin](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/ajaxdependancyselection/) to do some of the work for you. I haven't used the Grails plugin myself, but I have used the jQuery plugin and found it very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

or use the "noSelection" attribute of

```
<g:select ... noSelection="['':'-none-']"/>
```

then the "rebuild-script" will rebuild this empty no-selection automatically